# Left join but strip part of join key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL query

```
SELECT 
    productVariants.productKey
FROM
    [merchProductVariant] productVariants
LEFT JOIN 
    [merchInvoiceItem] invoices ON productVariants.sku = invoices.sku
WHERE 
    invoices.sku IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    productVariants.productKey
```

However, before I JOIN productVariants.sku on invoices.sku I need to strip some text from invoices.sku

An example would be, in the invoices.sku column. Some SKU's have been appended with a couple of custom strings. These are

```
|installed and |assembled
```

So in `merchProductVariant`, I'll have a SKU like this

```
123456
```

And in the invoices I'll have the same SKU but like this

```
123456  
123456|installed  
123456|assembled
```

I need to be able to strip those piped strings off so I can match them up. Or the query takes them as separate SKUs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTRING` on `invoices.sku` before joining like following code.

Appending an extra `'|'` in the end before doing the `SUBSTRING` to handle the scenario where there is no '|' character exists in the `invoices.sku` column.

```
SELECT 
    productVariants.productKey
FROM
    [merchProductVariant] productVariants
LEFT JOIN 
    [merchInvoiceItem] invoices ON productVariants.sku = SUBSTRING(invoices.sku +'|',0, CHARINDEX('|', invoices.sku + '|'))  
WHERE 
    invoices.sku IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    productVariants.productKey
```

It can be done using LIKE also in following way.

```
 ON  invoices.sku + '|' LIKE productVariants.sku + '|%'
```

Note:

> This is with the assumption that it's always going to be in the format
>   of sku|some_text. @leen3o - you might even want to add some explicit
>   CASTing in there if sku is always a number, an ID so to say. – MK_

Comment: This is with the assumption that it's always going to be in the format of `sku|some_text`. **@leen3o** - you might even want to add some explicit `CAST`ing in there if `sku` is always a number, an ID so to say.

Comment: Thanks  for pointing this out @MK_, I will update same in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. The format is always sku|some_text but sku is not always a number it can be any string. I'll out at the moment but will try this when I get back.

Answer (score 2):

For performance reasons, I would suggest that you add the "real" sku to the invoices table.  You can then index it and simplify your queries:

```
alter table merchInvoiceItem
    add sku_real as (left(sku, charindex('|', sku + '|')) persisted;

create index idx_merchInvoiceItem_sku_real on merchInvoiceItem(sku_real);
```

Then you can write the query as:

```
SELECT pv.productKey
FROM merchProductVariant mpv LEFT JOIN 
     merchInvoiceItem i
     ON mpv.sku = i.sku_real
WHERE i.sku IS NULL
GROUP BY pv.productKey;
```

Having the correct `sku` in the table should facilitate many queries written on the table.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `replace` function

```
productVariants.sku = replace(replace(invoices.sku, '|installed', ''), '|assembled', '')
```